# Nuxt.js/Vue.js dynamic images is not working

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm getting some data from an API that contains an image and some other information. Now there's a problem in Nuxt js or maybe I'm wrong. Whenever I supply the path to the image in the `:src` it just doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```html
<div v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="project.p_id" class="swiper-slide">
  <div :id="`index_${index}`" class="slide_wrapper">
    <div class="background">
      <img :src="getImgUrl(project.p_img_path)" alt="project cover image" />
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <div>
        <div class="left">
          <h2 style="color: black !impor tant">{{ project.p_label }}</h2>
          <small>{{ project.p_date }}</small>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <nuxt-link class="btn btn-secondary" to="/" @click="readMore">
            <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
          </nuxt-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

script:

```js
props: ['projects'],
methods: {
  readMore() {},
  getImgUrl(path) {
    return '../../../' + path
  },
},
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Last thing, whenever I use required `required('./assets/'+image.jpg')` nuxt.js crushes in compilation always stops at 69%. I also tried required.context but it didn't work as well.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "just doesn't work"? Have you inspected the page after to see what value is being set in the `src` attribute?

Comment: I've updated the post and btw the src value is completely right but for some reason, it's not working

Comment: We need to know where your images are stored within your nuxt app. Are you using /static? Or /assets?

Comment: I'm using assets just putting them inside my assets forlder

Comment: I updated the post @NickDawes

Answer (score 0):

In your template, change:

```
<img :src="getImgUrl(project.p_img_path)" alt="project cover image">
```

To:

```
<img :src="require(`../assets/${project.p_img_path}`)" alt="project cover image">
```

You shouldn’t need a method to return the path as a string, just use a template literal as above.

Ps. This assumes `project.p_img_path` = `img/project_img/filename.jpg`, so adjust as necessary.

Comment: I tried that already and I got an error it's not working I got lots of errors :(

Comment: I'm updating the post see the errors above

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I had to put all the images inside the assets folder directly. Thank you all for your time.